# findDOMNode console warning in material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to display an alert using Material UI. I have made a component using forwardRef as if not used it will also throw a findDOMnode error when rendered.

```
const AnnualMileageAlert = forwardRef( ( props, ref ) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState( true );

  return (
    <div {...props} ref={ref} className={classes.root}>
      <Collapse in={open}>
        <Alert
          action={(
            <IconButton
              aria-label="close"
              color="inherit"
              size="small"
              onClick={() => {
                setOpen( false );
              }}
            >
              <CloseIcon fontSize="inherit" />
            </IconButton>
          )}
          variant="filled"
          severity="warning"
        >
          <strong>1000000</strong>
        </Alert>
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  )
} );


export default AnnualMileageAlert;
```

This is being rendered in another file as follows:

```
const reference = createRef();

return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <div className="alert">{data > 100 ? <AnnualMileageAlert ref={reference}/> : null}</div>

      ...
    </form>
  );
```

When I click on the icon to close the alert, I have a warning in console:

```
Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.
```

I thought that by using forwardRef and passing the reference should have worked but for some reason it throws the warning when closing the alert.

Comment: Seems like it is a known [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13394) since 2018...

Comment: [Issue seems to be getting addressed in v5](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/183f267fa5995ea2c6c2abd4517164204e74382e/docs/src/pages/guides/migration-v4/migration-v4.md#non-ref-forwarding-class-components). Credit to [Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63365573/react-js-getting-react-class-refs-to-work).